# Accessing a pixel of an image with cv2

Tags: python, opencv

I would like to access and then recolor pixels of an image in Python. Several different tutorials, including [this one](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_core/py_basic_ops/py_basic_ops.html) uses this method to access a pixel:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
image = cv2.imread('ironman.bmp')
pixel = image[200, 500]
print pixel
```

I tried it, but after the `pixel = image[200, 500]` command I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    pixel = image[200, 500]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

After some research I figured out that the error message means that the value of `image[200, 500]` is `None`. But the tutorial uses this code without this problem. Could someone tell me what I might be doing wrong? I'm using Python 3.6.0.

Comment: Please check the value in`image`, I think It's `None`.

Comment: What are image layers? How about `pixel = image[200, 500, 0]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`image` is `None`. `cv2.imread` returns `None` when it cannot find the file. (A questionable design decision, in my opinion.)

```
>>> import cv2
>>> image = cv2.imread('does not exist')
>>> image is None
True
```

You almost certainly provided a wrong filename or the wrong relative path to the file. (The way you call `imread` currently the file would have to be in the same directory as your Python script.)

Comment: It seems that the problem was with the path I gave to the file. Although the path was right, one of the folders had letters outside of the american alphabet in it (é). After I renamed it the script ran without a problem. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

The code you have in place has no error in itself. You either have one of the following problems:

1. The image file you have mentioned is not present (or)
2. The image path has not been mentioned properly
3. Also ensure if the image format is mentioned correctly

I worked out your code for an image of my choice:

```
import cv2

#---I have passed the image path in a variable called filename which is accessed by cv2.imread() function---

filename = 'C:\\Users\\Mark\\Desktop\\stack\\Original.jpg'
image = cv2.imread(filename)
pixel = image[200, 500]
print pixel
```

The result:

```
[179 147  82]
```

In case you read a gray scale image, the result will be quite different:

```
filename = 'C:\\Users\\Mark\\Desktop\\stack\\Original.jpg'
image = cv2.imread(filename, 0)
pixel = image[200, 500]
print pixel
```

The result:

```
[131]
```